# Get the row that has just been inserted

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the id of the row that has just been inserted.

Currently, i'm using this code:

```
public long createEntryApp(String str_manid, String str_jobid, String str_engid, String str_app_type, 
        String str_appliances_model, String str_appliances_serial, String str_appliances_service_interval, String str_app_date)
{
    String lastRowId = "";

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    //inserting values in columns
    cv.put(KEY_APPLIANCES_MODEL, str_appliances_model);
    cv.put(KEY_MANUFACTURERROWID, str_manid);
    cv.put(KEY_APPLIANCES_TYPE, str_app_type);
    cv.put(KEY_JOBADDRESSFK, str_jobid);
    cv.put(KEY_APPLIANCES_SERIAL, str_appliances_serial);
    cv.put(KEY_APPLIANCES_SERVICE_INTERVAL, str_appliances_service_interval);
    cv.put(KEY_APPLIANCES_DATE, getDateTime());

    // getting the row id that has just been inserted

    String query = "SELECT KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID from TBL_APPLIANCES order by KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID DESC limit 1"; 
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);   // error is here
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        long lastId = c.getLong(0);
        lastRowId= String.valueOf(lastId);
    }
        Log.d("check last Row id", lastRowId); //checking if it's retrieved

    return ourDatabase.insert(TBL_APPLIANCES, null, cv);
}
```

where `KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID` =  rowId column and its `AUTOINCREMENTED`
       `TBL_APPLIANCES` = table name
 Error says :  There is no such table as `TBL_APPLIANCES` however it's in my database.
 Please help and thank you in advance: )

Comment: Never mind, just saw it. Answer don't below is my second guess. Sorry about useless comment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this however, i'm inserting using `ourDatabase.insert(TBL_APPLIANCES, null, cv);` where `database` is `db`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TBL_APPLIANCES` (and `KEY_*`) are variable names in your Java code and their *values* contain the SQL identifiers.

Therefore, replace

```
"SELECT KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID from TBL_APPLIANCES order by KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID DESC limit 1";
```

with something like

```
"SELECT " + KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID + " from " + TBL_APPLIANCES + " order by " + KEY_APPLIANCES_ROWID + " DESC limit 1";
```

On the other hand, you're doing the query before inserting anything so it won't return what you want.

Also, querying for values you just inserted is sort of redundant. You already know them. `insert()` returns the generated rowid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate, just testing it now and will let you know

Comment: It works when I remove `DESC limit 1` and shows the number of rows added which is 1 not the lastest rows id. Additionally, when I execute without removing `DESC limit 1` it says `no such column : appliances_idDESC`

Comment: Yes, of course you need a space between the column name and `DESC`.

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate it. Could you tell me a tutorial on how to master the syntax of the queries like the above you stated please.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it very easily if you use

**`db.insert()`** instead of `db.rawQuery()`

from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29):

> Returns
>
> the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

Comment: Thanks for replying SMR, i used `db.rawQuery()` as I don't know how to use `db.insert()` for my purpose. Please suggest me a tutorial so that I could learn different ways too.

Comment: sure this will be helpful http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @user3807650 cheers... you can always upvote or accept instead of saying thanx :P